# Any way to skip the Privacy Policy in Play Store at moment?

Tags: android, google-play

When I tried to upload my new APK file to Play Store, I got this error.

[image]

Is there any way to skip this Privacy Policy URL at moment since I don't have any Policy page at my website at moment.

I have checked "Not submitting a privacy policy URL at this time" at Store presence > Store listing.

Comment: The error is clear.  Stop requiring those permissions, or add a privacy policy page explaining what you will do with them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: you cannot.. read new policy requirement https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security/additional-requirements/

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to create your own Privacy Policy.

1. You can grab one copy from [my Github repo.](https://github.com/quangctkm9207/template-files/blob/master/common/PRIVACY-TEMPLATE.md)
2. Change your publisher name inside that file.
3. Host it somewhere else on internet (even in any of your Github repo or Gist file).
4. Add URL to GooglePlay.

I hosted that temple file for my personal use.